# Making my app Device Administrator

Tags: android, device, administrator

I am developing an Android application and I would like to make it a 'Device Administrator', but I do not quite understand how to do it. I've been looking over the API and tried to understand some examples, but I could not quite get the hang of it.
How should I approach this ?

Comment: You need the user to do it.  An app cannot make itself administrator or owner.  This is for obvious reasons-  if an app could give itself heightened permissions this is a big security hole.  Realistically only apps running on hardware you own or on hardware your company has access to (like employee devices) can use this functionality-  you'll never get random people off the Play Store to do it.

Comment: You can indeed prompt the user to enable it, be warned when it will be enabled, propose to disable it, and be warned when it has been disabled.

This is not really complicated just stick to a simple example, like this one, and you'll get it done: http://blogs.quovantis.com/android-device-administration-apis/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So, I guess I should prompt the user with the 'Device administrators' window, right? If so, how do I give the user the option to add my application to the list of device administrators?